# Java heap usage monitor

Tags: jboss7.x, rhq

I have decided to monitor maximum heap usage and used heap of my EAP applications (using rhq/JON3.3)
Pulled out both parameters for SINGLE node and it showing as max heap: 682.7MB and used heap to be 363.2MB

[image]

I also have pulled out the same for all the nodes in my environment and it is showing as max heap as 1.8G and used heap to be 1.4GB
[image]

My environment has more than 20 nodes,I checked the individual nodes and observed their heap usage to be more than 300 MB (each) so I concluded that Group metrics (second pic) displaying average (not sum) heap usage of all the nodes.
If my conclusion is wrong, what does the values in second pic means? If I am right, how to view the sum (not average) heap usage of all the nodes..

If you  are not getting what I am trying to say please let me know I will try much better to post my question clearly.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible for the resource groups to calculate the sum of all the member resource metrics. The average function is hardcoded here. However, there is also a rich CLI API in which you can achieve that by CLI scripts. Check the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Running+the+RHQ+CLI).

It's also doable by REST api, but unfortunately, no support in web UI, afaik.